# Using other projects in build path with Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have several projects (let's say 15). To make it easy let's consider each is like a library that generate one jar.
For this reason there is no "root" project. Any project can have dependencies on any other (without making circular dependencies of course).

A developer could be working on only one project, and only have its dependencies as jars that can be in a repository.

But they could also need to modify something in one of the dependency project and import it into their Eclipse.

At this point is there any way to define this dependency so that it will end up as a Project in the Eclipse build path ? I want Project_2 to use the live code from Project_1, not a generated jar.

It seems to me like a very basic requirement, yet I could not find anything related to that except a 7 year old question without answer.

I've seen solutions that more or less work with gradle, but they still don't generate the build path correctly and all implies a root project. There is no root project, someone working on Project_1 and Project_2 should not have to import Project_3 to 15 in their IDE just so that Gradle works correctly.

An easy way to switch between a jar or a project in settings.gradle would be ideal.

Update: Composite builds did not work last time I tried, but it looks better now. Still only works at one level.

/Project_A/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
}
```

/Project_B/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'undefined:project-A'
}
```

/Project_B/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'Project_B'

includeBuild('../Project_A'){
    dependencySubstitution{
        substitute module('undefined:project-A') with project(':')
    }
}
```

This seems to work. I can see the project in the dependencies (not the same as adding an actual project, but it looks like it does the job).

/Project_C/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'undefined:project-A'
    implementation 'undefined:project-B'
}
```

/Project_C/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'Project_C'

includeBuild('../Project_A'){
    dependencySubstitution{
        substitute module('undefined:project-A') with project(':')
    }
}

includeBuild('../Project_B'){
    dependencySubstitution{
        substitute module('undefined:project-B') with project(':')
    }
}
```

This does not work because **Multiple projects in the build are located in the same directory: C:\Workspace\Project_A**

It's ok in case I need to work on Project A, B and C. But if I wanted to only use Project C and A, and use B from a jar ?

And it's the simplest version, I have a lot more projects with much more complex dependencies.

This is the best result I got so far though.

I also tried using "project()" instead of "implementation" in the dependencies, or to include project in the settings.gradle.

I'm not sure if using "api" instead of "implementation" would have an effect.

Is there a way to write this include as a more complex function that would use the project or the jar according to a variable in settings.gradle, without having to comment/uncomment every includeBuild in the projects to make it work depending on the situation ?

Is there a way to refer to the projects by just their (unique) name or coordinates and not their path ?

Maybe I need to write a dependency resolver ?

Comment: Two things: Make sure to have `Project_A` vs. `project-a` etc. correct everywhere. Besides that, I think your `Project_C`-problem is a known limitation with a possible workaround: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/908#issuecomment-591377870 https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12356 I've attached some files I use in my build with Eclipse, have a look especially at those regarding `settings`.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same troubles, for me I've got a working solution by including project as dependency not as included build.

my settings.gradle in one project is looking like this:

```
   if (file('../otherProject').exists()) {
        include ':otherProject'
        project(':otherProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir,'../otherProject')
    }
```

Then I manipulated my dependencies with:

```
dependencies {
   if (file("../otherProject").exists()){
        api project(":otherProject")
    } else {
        api "foo.bar.otherProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    } 
}
```

The idea is like, "am I building on my local computer", then use the project instead of artifact.

Ontop I've created a task, for jar file used as loadable plugin.

```
task copyPluginToMainProject (type: Copy, group: "distribution" , description: "copy built plugin to Main Project", dependsOn: 'jar') {
    String destinationDir = "../mainProject/plugins/dir"
    into destinationDir
    from ("build/libs")
// these are additional libraries needed for the plugin running well 
    into ("/lib") {
      from configurations.runtimeClasspath include "mariadb*.jar"
    }
}
```

This task is copying the built jar and needed libraries on the main project.
You could follow this solution as well, to build your libs locally and then let it copy to a well know library path.